# How to create template message without title and with long subtitle in messenger bot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

in the [Facebook messenger docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template) the generic template must contain title and the subtitle can only be 80 characters long.

What message type did CNBC use to create this message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button template.

The documentation is here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/button-template

Comment: Thank you. Did not realize there is a difference between button and button template.